# Is there a way to configure Firebase Storage to grant anonymous access only from devices?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm developing a mobile app and I would like to know if it's possible to use Firebase Storage but only granting access from my app, and avoiding access by web.

Thanks in advance!